# How can I prove these inequalities involving PGF?

Tags: inequality

I need to prove two inequalities but I have no idea to prove it.

$\Bbb P(X\le x_0)\le(\frac{\phi_x(t)}{t^{x_0}}),t\in[0,1]$

$\Bbb P(X\ge x_0)\le(\frac{\phi_x(t)}{t^{x_0}}),t\ge1$

$\phi_X(t)$ is the probability generating function of non-negative discrete random variable X.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\begin{align}
\phi_X(t) &= \sum_{x} p(x)t^x \tag{1} \\ 
&=\sum_{x \leq x_0} p(x)t^x + \sum_{x>x_0} p(x)t^x \tag{2} \\
&=t^{x_0}\sum_{x \leq x_0} \frac{p(x)}{t^{x_0-x}} + \sum_{x>x_0} p(x)t^x \tag{3}
\end{align}
Now $\sum_{x \leq x_0} \frac{p(x)}{t^{x_0-x}}$ takes its smallest value in $t \in [0,1]$ at $t=1$ with a value of $$\sum_{x \leq x_0} p(x) = \mathbb{P}(X \leq x_0) \tag{4}$$
and since $\sum_{x>x_0} p(x)t^x$ is positive
$$\phi_X(t) \geq t^{x_0}\mathbb{P}(X \leq x_0). \tag{5}$$
Argue similarly for the other inequality.

Comment: I'm so grateful for your solution! Thx!

Comment: @CauchyBR that's great, glad to help. You should mark it as accepted to identify the question as resolved.